# How should I add custom brand slider in magento site.?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css

I am new user of Magento.I am try to add owl carousel but it doesn't showing on my home page.
I added the css and js in magento\skin\frontend\rwd\default\ pathin css and js folder respectively and create on static block for at admin and added following html code:-

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item"><h1>0</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>1</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>2</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>3</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>4</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>5</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>6</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>7</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>8</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>9</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>10</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>11</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>12</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>13</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>14</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>15</h1></div>
</div>
```

and I want to display it on home page so added a static block widget(i.e. brand)on home page. also added following code at layout xml section:-

```
<reference name="head">
 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js</name></actio‌​n> 
 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/owl.carousel.js</name></action>
 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/owl.carousel.min.js</name></action>
 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/owl.homepage.js</name></action>
<action method="addCss"><type>skin_css</type><name>skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/owl.carousel.css</name></action> 
<action method="addCss"><type>skin_css</type><name>skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/owl.theme.css</name></action> 
<action method="addCss"><type>skin_css</type><name>skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/owl.transitions.css</name></actio‌​n> 
</reference>
```

still it not showing in home page at frnt end..
If anything is wrong then please suggest me suitable solution to implement this activity...

Answer (score 3):

Magento will determine the template and package path for you so all you need to add for JS and CSS is

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/owl.carousel.js</name></action>
```

I do see some JS files are added as CSS files, try the following

```
<reference name="head">
 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js</name></actio‌​n> 
 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/owl.carousel.js</name></action>
 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/owl.carousel.min.js</name></action>
 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/owl.homepage.js</name></action>
<action method="addCss"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/owl.carousel.css</name></action> 
<action method="addCss"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/owl.theme.css</name></action> 
<action method="addCss"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/owl.transitions.css</name></actio‌​n> 
</reference>
```